# Java - Accessing object created in different 'if/else if' statement?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, while-loop, constructor

I'm currently working on a project (a very simple makeshift bookstore) where I have two classes (one for managing a User Account and one functioning as a driver class), in which a menu is presented to the user via the main method of the driver class. This menu, as per the project specifications, is represented by a **while** loop in which the user types a single character corresponding to one of several menu options. Within this **while** loop is a series of **if**/**else if** statements, with each of these statements containing the code for one of the menu options. These menu options are as follows:

```
Main Menu:

N - Create account
L - Load money into your account balance
O - Order a book
S - Print an account summary
X - Quit
```

The purpose of the **while** loop, I presume, is to keep cycling back to the main menu after the user works through the various sub-menus, ending only when the user input is "X".

When the user input is "N" and the *'Create account'* menu is launched, the following code is executed:

```
if(menuInput == 'N') {
            // Scanner sc has already been declared at top of main method

            System.out.println("Enter your desired username:");
            in_userName = sc.next();
            // String in_userName has already been declared at top of main method

            System.out.println("Enter a starting balance:");
            in_initBal = sc.nextDouble();
            // double in_initBal has already been declared at top of main method

            UserAccount user = new UserAccount(in_userName,in_initBal);
            accountCheck = true;

         /* accountCheck is a boolean that makes sure an account has been
            created; it has already been declared/initialized to 'false' 
            prior to the while loop
         */

}
```

The only other menu option in the driver class I've programmed so far is *'L - Load money into your account balance'*. The code for this menu option is as follows:

```
else if(menuInput == 'L') {
            if(accountCheck == false) {
                System.out.println("You must create an account first. Enter N                                                                      
                                    to create one.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Enter the amount to add:");
                in_amountToAdd = sc.nextDouble(); 
                // double in_amountToAdd has already been declared at top of main method   

                user.addToBalance(in_amountToAdd);     /* Method in the User Account class
                                                          that takes a double parameter and
                                                          adds it to the existing balance.
                                                       */
                System.out.println(user.getBalance());
            }
```

The problem is that the *user.addToBalance(in_amountToAdd)* and *System.out.println(user.getBalance())* lines don't compile, because *"user cannot be resolved"*. I created the constructor in the **if** statement corresponding to the *'Create account'* option but don't know how to implement it in other **if**/**else if** blocks, so I was wondering if there is a way for me to either:

1. Get the **if** statement for the *'Load money into account'* sub-menu to recognize the **"user"** constructor from the *'Create account'* sub-menu, so that the code I've included here will compile, or:
2. Initialize the **"user"** constructor at the beginning of the main method, and then change/update its argument parameters to the input values from the **scanner** later on.

My thought process for number two on the above list is that declaring/initializing the constructor *before* the while loop would allow each **if**/**else if** block to see it, whereas it seems only the *'Create account'* block can see it as of right now (I'm guessing this is because the constructor was created here and is local to just this particular **if** statement).

I apologize in advance if any of the terminology I've used is wrong or inaccurate, and if any of my code is confusing/impractical. I am just a beginner, so I'd appreciate it if you guys would point out any mistakes I've made to serve as a learning experience for me.

Thanks!

Comment: The `User` instance `user` exists only within the ***block*** (identified by the nearest open- and close-braces (`{` and `}`) surrounding the declaration.  Outside that block the variable does not exist.

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. You should not use the underbar character for variable names. And for your actual question, you should learn about the differences between local variables and the fields of a class for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable before the `while` loop and the `if-else`

e.g.

```
UserAccount user = null;

while (...) {
    if (...) {
      user = new UserAccount(in_userName,in_initBal);
    }
    else {
       user.addToBalance(in_amountToAdd); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `UserAccount user` before your `While` loop.

```
UserAccount user = null;

// while not "Exit"
while (menuInput != 'X') {

    if (menuInput == 'N') {
        user = new UserAccount(in_userName,in_initBal);
    }
    else if(menuInput == 'L') {

        // check if UserAccount is created
        if (user != null) {
            user.addToBalance(in_amountToAdd);
        }

    }

    .....
}
```

With this, you can eliminate `accountCheck` boolean variable, as similar check can be done to check whether `user` is null.